# Sync Mail to MySQL

Tags: mysql, email, synchronization

I've been given the task to synchronize our mail to our MySQL database. 
Is there an easy way that I can do this? Or can you guys suggest any software available for this?

Thank You.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Sync in what way? Are you talking about the mails that where already downloaded via pop or imap on a local machine somewhere to be synced with a database or is this supposed to be happening online on some server – directly in the mailbox? And why do they need to be in a database?

Answer (score 0):

[Zapier](http://zapier.com) can help you build connections between two services, including email and MySQL.